# Read XMP from existing PDF with iTextSharp

Tags: pdf, itext, xmp

How can I read XMP from an existing PDF file using iTextSharp?

Answer (score 4):

I'm dangerously ignorant of itextSharp but this did the job for me:

```
    PdfReader pdf = new PdfReader(fileName);
    string metadataXml = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(pdf.Metadata);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd encourage you to check out the `iTextSharp.text.xml.xmp` namespace.

I've never done what you're trying to do but the `XmpReader` class looks promising.

Comment: Info: `iTextSharp.text.xml.xmp.XmlReader` is obsolete.