# set pdf properties from reporting services

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, properties

I have a RDL that I call from .net code and I render it as PDF. RS sets values for the properties of the documents such as author, title, subject.

Can I change those properties at runtime when the RDL is executed?

Thanks a lot,

Edgar

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. though the specifics of how to do this depends on what metadata you are trying to set (ie if it's xmp data or the document metadata).

Comment: Ok, I'll be a little more specific: any of both would be usefull if I can read it with iTextSharp, because I need to read specific data that that comes from the RDL. But I need know if I can add data to the PDF from the reporting services (different to the report).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522101/read-xmp-from-existing-pdf-with-itextsharp That post says you can read xmp. otherwise you can use the addSubject, addAuthor (etc) methods to update the document metadata of an existing pdf.  You just have to read it, add the metadata, and write it back out. Here is some sample code http://forums.asp.net/t/1333428.aspx

Comment: Hi,
Using the itextsharp is OK, the part that i don't know is how can I set XMP or metadata to the PDF file when is rendered in RS.
In other words, in RS I need to add dynamic information (some result, like client name), later I'll read it (with itextsharp)

Thanks